# Where do I put the Houzz Badge code?

Tags: theming, blocks

I'd like to add a Best of Houzz badge on our site.  I have the code, but don't know where to put it.

Is it Admin --> structure --> ... then what?

Since the site was built by someone else and now I'm maintaining it, I really don' want to mess anything up by poking around and "experimenting."

Answer (score 1):

Go to: *YOUR_SITE/admin/structure/block/add* and fill the info like this:

[image]

In *Block body* field you must put the code of the badge and go to the bottom of the page to *Save block*.

Then in the YOUR_SITE/admin/structure/block page search your block, in this case the name is "*Best of Houzz badge*" then select the region where the block will be displayed (in this case `Sidebar first`)

[image]

Go to the bottom of the page and click in the *Save blocks* button.

And you will see the block in your site.

Comment: thank you so much.  I'll check that out.  Have a great day!

Comment: @Caynine A pleasure, let me know the result ;-)

Comment: @Caynine If my answer help you consider accept it as correct, if you don't know how you can read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour